# Xamarin ViewCell: how to turn off > touch action?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using `ViewCell` with `TableView` it shows a right arrow `>` (circled in red) and the whole cell can be touched - I suppose to select it and slide a new page from right to left to "drill into details".

Can someone advise on how to disable the display of `>` ?
Looks that `ViewCell.IsEnabled =  false` turns off the touch action.

[image]

Here is some code in my class deriving from `ContentPage` that creates the table section:

```
public class SamplePage : ContentPage
{

    public SamplePage()
    {
        var gridLengthStar = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);

        // GRIDSAMPLE CODE
        var gridSample = new Grid
        {
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto},
                new RowDefinition {Height = GridLength.Auto}
            },
            Padding = new Thickness(20, 20, 20, 20),
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = gridLengthStar},
                new ColumnDefinition {Width = gridLengthStar}
            },
        };

        gridSample.Children.Add ( new Label() { Text = "Data1" }, 0, 0);
        gridSample.Children.Add ( new Label() { Text = "Data2" }, 1, 0);

        gridSample.Children.Add ( new Label() { Text = "Data3" }, 0, 1);
        gridSample.Children.Add ( new Label() { Text = "Data4" }, 1, 1);

        var tableView = new TableView
        {
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
        };

        tableView.Root = new TableRoot
        {
            new TableSection("SECTION TITLE")
            {
                (new ViewCell {View = gridSample, IsEnabled =  false})
            }
        };

        Content = new StackLayout()
            {
                Children = { tableView } ,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                Spacing = 10
            };

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the tableView's Intent to something other than TableIntent.Form? Maybe try TableIntent.Data.

Comment: @deckertron_9000 - yep tried all intents, it did not affect the arrow.

Comment: on Xamarin forums MichaelRumpler suggested that I have `Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;` (for iOS) set somewhere, which I will investigate today.

Comment: If you have a custom renderer that could definitely be the case. You would need to change the native iOS view's disclosure indicator to UITableViewCellAccessory.None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That arrow can be shown on iOS if you set

```
Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
```

in your UITableViewCell.

Xamarin.Forms usually doesn't set this, so the arrow should not be shown. If it is there, then you have some renderer, Effect or other component which sets it in the iOS code.

Comment: There was a custom renderer in the project that added DisclosureIndicator, thanks for your help